# Switch between activities without restarting or reloading the activity

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity, bottomnavigationview

I am using bottomNavigation in my application. I have 2 menu items (home,search ). I don't want to restart home activity every time a user tries to switch back to home activity from some other activity. I have tried adding FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT in my intent but it doesn't work.

**searchActivity**

```
 bottomNavigationView.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener(new BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
            switch (item.getItemId()){
                case R.id.home:
                    Intent intent = new Intent();
                    startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(),MainActivity.class));
                    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT);
                    overridePendingTransition(0,0);
                    return true;
                case R.id.search:
                    break;
            return false;
        }
    });
```

Comment: you mean home fragment not activity ?

Comment: I am not using home fragments. Actually I am new to android development. I am using activities only

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this. By the help of `active` fragment we just just hide the active fragment, show new one.

MainActivty.java

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

final Fragment fragment_home = new HomeFragment();
final Fragment fragment_search = new DashboardFragment();
final FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
Fragment active = fragment_home;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


    BottomNavigationView navigation = (BottomNavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
    navigation.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener(mOnNavigationItemSelectedListener);

    fm.beginTransaction().add(R.id.nav_host_fragment, fragment_search, "fragment_search").hide(fragment_search).commit();
    fm.beginTransaction().add(R.id.nav_host_fragment, fragment_home, "fragment_home").commit();

}


private BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener mOnNavigationItemSelectedListener
        = new BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {

    @Override
    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.navigation_home:
                fm.beginTransaction().hide(active).show(fragment_home).commit();
                active = fragment_home;
                return true;

            case R.id.navigation_dashboard:
                fm.beginTransaction().hide(active).show(fragment_search).commit();
                active = fragment_search;
                return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
};}
```

Comment: @YunisRasulzda I don't have a home fragment. Main Activity opens on clicking the home button from bottom navigation. Can you please tell me how to solve this problem without using fragment.